# How do you find a range in an array? Note: the values within the range must list all possible permutations

Tags: arrays, vba, comparison

I'm working on a statistical code/function that will return a probability measure. the problem lies when checking if a range is within the array or not. This range however can also change according to a set criteria.

Lets say you have array with 25rows and 2 columns. in this instance A1:B25
the first range you want to check within this array is A1:B1 within array A1:B25.

with certain criteria included this range values can change. if the array in two columns is

```
9   4
4   8
8   1
1   2
2   4
```

And the range you want to check is

```
9   4
```

, and criteria is 1 (+-1), meaning that we want to find this range between -1 and 1 in the array. 
so the first check would be to see if {9, 4} exists, it does since the two rang itself is there, return 1 found, but {9,5} {10,5}   {10,4}  {9,3}   {8,4}   {8,5}   {10,3}  {8,3}, doesn't exist in the array and returns nothing. so only 1 value found.

Apologies if i am not explaining this properly. hopefully the below image helps.
click this : 
[excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQFnT.png)

I can find the values {8, 3} {9, 4} {10, 5} in the array, hence with these criteria, {-1, -1} {0, 0} {1, 1} in the array (the two columns), but not {-1 ,0} {0, -1}  {1, -1} {-1, 1} {-1, -1}.

Which brings me to my problem.

the code below finds each range within the array. but only how many times it sees itself in the array. so no permutations within the tolerance of +-r

```
Sub get_matches()
'note this isnt dynamic and only works for columns of 2
Dim arr() As Variant, trr As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Double
Dim ans As Double, r As Double

ans = 0
m = 2
arr = Range("A2:B26").value

For k = 2 To 26
trr = Range("A" & k & ":B" & k).value
For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)  ' Iterate through the rows of the array
For j = 1 To UBound(arr, m)  'iterate through the columns of the array
If arr(i, j) = trr(1, j) Then
j = j + 1
If j <= m Then
If arr(i, j) = trr(1, j) Then
ans = ans + 1
Else
ans = ans
End If
End If
End If
Next
Next
Range("N" & k).value = ans
ans = 0
Next k
```

To mention, the initial array that i have is dynamic. so the range size can change, and the array size can also change depending on the criteria.
bounds for the array(1 to rowcount, 1 to columncount)
range(i, 1 to columncount) if you understand what i mean. 
so the size can change.

for instance:

```
Function ChangeMatrixTwo(ByRef inputCol As Range, NumCols As Long) As 
Variant

'recreate the range of your data into the different vector sizes.
'the vector size m and m+1 
'by resizing the range into the vector wanted with values following after 
each other
'to better explain, should you have a series 123456, for vector 2, it will 
return {1,2} {2,3} {3,4} {4,5} {5,6}

Dim NewMatrix() As Variant
Dim i, j, k, n As Long
Dim rowsize As Long

n = inputCol.Count
rowsize = n - NumCols + 1

ReDim NewMatrix(1 To rowsize, 1 To NumCols)
k = 1
For i = 1 To rowsize
For j = 1 To NumCols
NewMatrix(i, j) = inputCol(k, 1)
k = k + 1
Next j
k = k - NumCols + 1
Next i
ChangeMatrixTwo = NewMatrix
End Function
```

by changing column number i can generate an m and m+1 matrix/array
and this i must combine with my inital problem ><

Comment: Sorry, I'm baffled by your question! Might be me. Can you post a screenshot or try some other way of elucidating your problem?

Comment: Is this a question >> is A1:A1 within array A1:B26 << ??  Is it a question of whether two ranges overlap? (totally, partially, not at all)??

Then I am lost-- what does this mean, this string of numbers. It is too long to fit in A1:A1, and too short to fit in A1:B26.  
And breaks continuity with the prior sentence and problem development.
 >> if array 9 4 4 8 8 1 1 2 2 4 <<  I AM LOST...

Comment: Apologies @donPablo ; i tried rewriting the question and the range would be A1:B1 within the columns A1:B25 (which is the array). I'll try to add images to better explain.

Comment: @SJR i added an image. the columns A2:B26 is the array. and within columns E to L are the different permutations of each row in columns A:B. I need to find whether each permutation exists in that array. Column C are my findings. Now I would like to create this in VBA and make it dynamic for any array size with any criteria size. if r = 2, then we would need permutations of -2, -1, 0, 1, 2. if you follow?

Comment: That picture makes it clearer. So the figure in column C is the number of instances of e.g. 9,4 in the whole range E-L? It looks like your problem comes down mainly to permutations. Would you expect 24 columns for r=2?

Comment: i must find each permutation with a +-1 or +-2 (depending on the criteria r) within the array yes.

Comment: @SJR we need to include a column for (0,0) for r=1, and 3*3 = 9.  And thus for r=2 there are five values, and 5*5 =  25 columns.

Comment: @MugiB Are there any cases in the example xls where a Negative item could convert to an Absolute value that does Not duplicate ??  The yellow highlights all seem to be Negative, but would Duplicate an existing item. Or have I missed something?  I am trying to test a subprogram to convert Negatives to Unique items.

Answer (score 0):

```
How do you find a range in an array?
I find it very difficult.
Needed to do major surgery on this.  
>finds each permutation within the tolerance of +-rTolerance
>dynamic and works for any columns
>Missing is any correction for Negative values in PermutedARow
>Missing is ChangeMatrixTwo

Option Explicit

Sub doit()
    ' example of your calling syntax

     get_matches   ' pass no args, use default values

    ' or pass any args using colon&equals :=   and separate args with commas
    get_matches argResultColumn:="C"

End Sub


Sub get_matches(Optional argSheet As String = "Sheet1", Optional argRange As String = "A2:B26", _
     Optional argTolerance As String = "1", Optional argResultColumn As String = "N")

    ' note: the code below finds each permutation within the tolerance of +-rTolerance
    ' note: this is dynamic and works for any columns

    Sheets(argSheet).Select


    Dim Arr() As Variant, AmaxRows As Long, AmaxCols As Long, ARow As Long, ACol As Long
    Arr = Range(argRange).Value
    ' e.g. base is cell(2,"A"), aka "A2",  and numRows is 25, and numCols is 2
    AmaxRows = UBound(Arr, 1) - LBound(Arr, 1) + 1
    AmaxCols = UBound(Arr, 2) - LBound(Arr, 2) + 1
    'MsgBox ("r=" & AmaxRows & " C=" & AmaxCols & "  L1=" & LBound(Arr, 1) & " U1=" & UBound(Arr, 1) & "  L2=" & LBound(Arr, 2) & " U2=" & UBound(Arr, 2))

    ' create array of Tolerances -- e.g. tol=2 has array of  -2, -1, 0, 1, 2
    Dim rTolerance As Long, rNdx As Long, rTolMax As Long, rTolRange() As Variant, rx As Long
    rTolerance = argTolerance      ' could be = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
    rTolMax = ((rTolerance + rTolerance) + 1)
    ReDim rTolRange(0 To rTolMax - 1) As Variant
    rx = -1 * rTolerance
    For rNdx = LBound(rTolRange, 1) To UBound(rTolRange, 1)
        rTolRange(rNdx) = rx
        rx = rx + 1
    Next rNdx

    ' create Permutations array, and have subprogram compute the items
    Dim Permutations() As Variant
    ReDim Permutations(0 To (rTolMax ^ AmaxCols) - 1, 0 To AmaxCols - 1) As Variant
    Call ComputePermutations(rTolMax, rTolRange, Permutations)


    ' BIG LOOP--step down the Array rows
    For ARow = 1 To AmaxRows ' 2 To 26

        ' clone Permutations into PermutedARow, and add in  Arr(ARow) across each item
        Dim PermutedARow() As Variant
        PermutedARow = Permutations
        For rNdx = 0 To UBound(PermutedARow, 1)
            For ACol = 0 To UBound(PermutedARow, 2)
                PermutedARow(rNdx, ACol) = PermutedARow(rNdx, ACol) + Arr(ARow, ACol + 1)
            Next ACol
        Next rNdx

'====>>> This does not handle NEGATIVE value(s) in an Item in PermutedARow
'====>>> Unique ABSOLUTE valued items should be allowed
'====>>> (non-unique ones stay negative so we don't double count)
'====>>> can only be done after entire PermutedARow is made.


        ' now restart at the top of the Array and look/count each matching PermutedARow-s to each Arr row
        Dim iRow As Long, jCol As Long
        Dim ans As Long
        ans = 0

        ' for each row in the array
        For iRow = 1 To AmaxRows              ' Iterate through the rows of the Array

            ' match to each set of adjusted columns
            For rNdx = 0 To UBound(PermutedARow, 1)

                ' assume EQ
                Dim compared As String
                compared = "EQ"

                ' compare its columns to adjusted columns
                For ACol = 0 To UBound(PermutedARow, 2)          ' iterate through the columns of the Array

                    If PermutedARow(rNdx, ACol) <> Arr(iRow, ACol + 1) Then
                        compared = "NE"
                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next ACol

                If compared = "EQ" Then
                    ans = ans + 1
                End If

            Next rNdx

        Next iRow
        Range(argResultColumn & ARow + 1).Value = ans

    Next ARow
End Sub


Sub ComputePermutations(rTolMax As Long, rTolRange() As Variant, Permutations() As Variant)
    ' 2 cols, rTol=1 ==> 0-8, 0-1
    ' 3 cols, rTol=1 ==> 0-26, 0-1
    ' 3 cols, rTol=2 ==> 0-26, 0-2

    Dim whichTolItem As Long, colOfTolItem As Long
    Dim Dividend As Long, Divisor As Long, Quotient As Long, Remainder As Long

    For whichTolItem = 0 To UBound(Permutations, 1)

        Dividend = whichTolItem

        For colOfTolItem = 0 To UBound(Permutations, 2) - 1 'maxCol - 1
            Divisor = rTolMax ^ (UBound(Permutations, 2) - colOfTolItem)
            Quotient = Dividend \ Divisor  ' integer division
            Permutations(whichTolItem, colOfTolItem) = rTolRange(Quotient)
        Next colOfTolItem

        Remainder = Dividend Mod Divisor
        Permutations(whichTolItem, colOfTolItem) = rTolRange(Remainder)


'        ' un-comment this to show the various Permutations
'        Dim prt As String
'        prt = ""
'        Debug.Print " "
'        For colOfTolItem = 0 To UBound(Permutations, 2)
'            prt = prt & " , " & Permutations(whichTolItem, colOfTolItem)
'        Next colOfTolItem
'        Debug.Print whichTolItem, prt

    Next whichTolItem

End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies for my late reply. I tested it for two columns and it seemed to work. Havent gotten to test it for more than three columns. I did however create a function that counts it for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function ApCounter(BigArray As Range, CompareArr As Variant, Crit As Integer)
'function to count a range within the array that is within a certain bounds
'the array is BigArray and the range we finding is the CompareArr, the bounds we call Crit

Dim i, j, rowSize, colSize As Long
Dim ans As Double
Dim r As Integer
Dim counter As Double

counter = 0
ans = 0
rowSize = BigArray.Rows.Count
colSize = BigArray.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To rowSize  ' Iterate through the rows of the array
    For j = 1 To colSize 'iterate through the columns of the array
        For r = -Crit To Crit 'iterate alternate values
            Do While BigArray(i, j) = CompareArr(1, j) + r
                counter = counter + 1
                r = r + 1
            Loop
            If counter = colSize Then
                ans = ans + 1
            Exit For
            Else
                ans = ans
            End If
        Next
    Next
    counter = 0
Next
 ApCounter = ans

End Function
```